# Перебор результатов .querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Создаю выпадающее многоуровневое меню.
Проблема в том, что функция не срабатывает на тех элементах, которые идут после элемента, неудовлетворяющего условие `if`.
Приведенный код - упрощенный аналог функционала: по клику надо окрасить то, что кликнуто при условии, что рядом есть ещё один элемент.
Вопрос: как заставить функцию работать со всеми элементами, у которых есть "сосед".

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  var sublist = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list li a');
  for (var i=0; i<sublist.length; i++) {
    if (sublist[i].nextSibling.length !== null) {
      sublist[i].onclick = function(event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        this.style.background = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-list">
  <li><a href="#">111</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">222</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">444</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">555</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">666</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">777</a><span>000</span></li>
</div>
```

Comment: `sublist[i].nextSibling` возвращает следующего предка, а это объект DOM модели, у него нет свойства `.length` оно всегда `undefined` либо ошибка `Cannot read property 'length' of null(…)` если предка вовсе нет

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев хм. под span я подразумеваю второй уровень меню. я размышлял так: если этот второй уровень меню будет, то надо его развернуть. если нет, то ничего не делать. вот и проверяю, если ли рядом с элементов ещё что-то через `.nextSibling.length !== null` . как тогда лучше реализовать показ подменю?

Comment: а почему бы тогда не выбрать не по `a`, а по `li` - `.dropdown-list li`, тогда ты можешь узнать сколько будет детей внутри `li` с помощью `childElementCount`. И ты будешь знать что 1 - это только ссылка, а 2 это ссылка и `span`, твой второй уровень. Это если я тебя правильно понимаю)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев да, то, что надо, судя по всему) пока полёт нормальный. спс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  var sublist = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list li');
  for (var i = 0; i < sublist.length; i++) {
    if (sublist[i].childElementCount === 2) {
      sublist[i].onclick = function(event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        this.querySelector('span').style.background = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-list">
  <li><a href="#">111</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">222</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">444</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">555</a><span>000</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">666</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">777</a><span>000</span></li>
</div>
```

Т.к. у `.nextSibling` нет свойства `.length`, изменил код, сделав проверку не через искомый элемент на существование соседнего элемента у родителя, а на существование нескольких (в моем случае двух) чайлдов у родителя, используя `.childElementCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно выбрать все спаны соседствующие с ссылками, а дальше в цикле брать предыдущий элемент - он как раз будет ссылкой.

Подробнее про [смежные селекторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Например:

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  var sublist = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list li a + span');
  [].forEach.call(sublist, function(span) {
    var a = span.previousElementSibling;
    a.onclick = function(event) {
      // event.preventDefault();
      this.style.background = 'red';
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-list">
  <li><a href="#">111</a><span>000</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">222</a><span>000</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><span>000</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">444</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">555</a><span>000</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">666</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">777</a><span>000</span>
  </li>
</div>
```